# webpack-dev-middleware can't Hot Reload on route's path

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

I'm putting webpack-dev-middleware on my express route which points to `/login` with this:

```
(async () => {
        const [
            {default: webpack},
            {default: webpackMW},
            {default: webpackHMR},
            {default: webpack_login_cfg}
        ] = await Promise.all([
            import('webpack'),
            import('webpack-dev-middleware'),
            import('webpack-hot-middleware'),
            import('../cfg/wp_hmr_login.js')
        ]),
        compiler = webpack(webpack_login_cfg)
        router.use(webpackMW(compiler, { publicPath: '/'}))
        router.use(webpackHMR(compiler))
    })()
```

webpack middleware works but hot reloading doesn't. In `wp_hmr_login.js`, I make use of html-webpack-plugin and set `publicPath: '/login/'` which equals to `publicPath: '/'` in middleware's config (I already tried setting these two to everything else, including `output.publicPath`, `''`, `'/'`, removing it etc but they all give me "cannot GET /xxx" because the bundle have a different location to what html plugin expects). In logs, you can see why hot reloading isn't working: `GET /login/login.b0139afc0a4838fcda0e.hot-update.json 404`.
Looks like webpack is putting or looking for hot-update.json in the wrong place. I tried looking for the file at `/main.b0139afc0a4838fcda0e.hot-update.json` but it doesn't seem to be there at all. One important note is that the same code structure works perfectly on my index route, which points to `/`. Any idea on how to get around this would be very interesting to look at.

EDIT: I discovered that by adding `?path=/login` at the end of `['webpack-hot-middleware/client...` removes the 404 on hot-update.json, I can in fact now see in the console:

```
asset login.893cfc7bf76f6dbbc8a2.hot-update.js 3.19 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: login)
asset index.html 426 bytes [emitted]
asset login.893cfc7bf76f6dbbc8a2.hot-update.json 29 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
```

but hot-reloading still doesn't work on routes different to `'/'`

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve this and report it here for anyone having the same issue:

added `?dynamicPublicPath=true` at the end of `[webpack-hot-middleware/client...` as its only parameter and set the output `publicPath` to the route's path, in this specific case `/login/`.